# Free Master Pages to use?

Tags: master-page

I wonder if there are some basic and professional look master pages that we can freely use?
(I am not looking anything complex but not want to use v4 and nightandday masters)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the master pages here:

http://lifeinsharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/78033

http://kyleschaeffer.com/sharepoint/v5-responsive-html5-master-page/

Comment: thanks very much but actually i dont want metro or html5 style master page. i rather look for a standard master page with different look & feel (simple but professional)

Answer (score 0):

This should be a good start - [SharePoint Master Pages](http://sharepointmasterpages.com/)

Update:

[This](http://lifeinsharepoint.codeplex.com/releases) as well if you want the new SP2013 look on your SP2010

Comment: thank you dandroid, are your sure those master pages in sharepointmasterpages dot com FREE ?

Comment: @10010111001101 Not all of them.

Comment: can you give me the link of any free master page. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this also:

[Starter MasterPages for SharePoint](http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/)

[Improved SharePoint Starter MasterPage](http://labs.steveottenad.com/improved-sharepoint-2010-starter-master-page/)